# Images loading on localhost but not using IP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using a PHP script to read some folders in directory and based on their names retrieve their posters. All of this works fine on `localhost`. However, when opening externally, this does not work and results in `blank` images.

A screenshot from localhost:[image: Screenshot of localhost]

---

The problem can be found at `89.241.171.100/Prac/`.
PHP generating `img tag`:

```
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
      $counter++;
      echo "<span class='title'>
              <img src='holder.js/200x280/text:$entry' 
                   alt='$entry' 
                   onload='loader(this, \"$entry\")' />
                   </span>";
      if($counter == 5) break;
 }
```

PHP fetching the src for the images called via ajax from `loader()`:

```
if($_POST['title']) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $imdb = new Imdb();
    $movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("$title");
    $link = $movieArray["poster_large"];
    echo $link;
}
```

`Loader()` function:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'loader.php',
     data: 'title='+title,
     success: function(data) {
          img.src = data;
     }
 });
```

Comment: You'll need to show the HTML you use to show the image

Comment: try root relative paths instead.

Comment: Please post the PHP - and include the output of what happens when your echo/var_dump the file path.

Comment: use browser console to look at paths being requested

Comment: When I try to go to that URL, it sends a redirect to `localhost:8888/Prac`. Since I'm not running a webserver on localhost, it doesn't work.

Comment: where is the `loader` function?

Comment: @RaheelHasan: Added, please have another look!

Comment: @Barmar: Fixed the issue, try the new URL `89.241.171.100/Prac/`

Comment: This should be `cross-domain` issue, some reference http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html may be imdb is blocking other site ip, only accept `localhost`

Comment: what is `img` in loader function? I dont see it initialized?

Comment: can you do 1 thing? put `alert(data)` inside `success: function(data)` and see what is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the way you're loading it.  These images are being provided via Akamai's CDN and it's not liking the referrer that it's getting.

Here's what's being returned instead of the image payload.

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Referral Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Referral Denied</H1>
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;ia&#46;media&#45;imdb&#46;com&#47;images&#47;M&#47;MV5BMTM5NjM0ODY1NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjk5NjI0Ng&#64;&#64;&#46;&#95;V1&#46;&#95;SY500&#46;jpg" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;24&#46;24c633b8&#46;1366714063&#46;2a353f15
</BODY></HTML>
```

I'm not encouraging breaching anyone's terms but [this](http://referrer-killer.googlecode.com/git/example.html) might be of some use to you, I suspect that passing an empty referrer will fix the problem as when you visit the image URL directly it works (and doesn't send a referrer).

EDIT:

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndM4S/) is a working example of what I was suggesting earlier.  You'll notice the image directly linked is dead, but the one with no referrer loads perfectly.

Comment: Fixed! Please give it another try? using the new URL: `89.241.171.100/Prac/`

Comment: Still not working for me, I think your browser might have now cached the images.  Can you try adding a different movie?

Comment: It works will other additional movies too, it just doesn't work when using it via the IP

Comment: Oh cool, so the requests work ok when the referrer FQDN rather than an IP address, glad that you worked it out in the end.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, but it was working on localhost before too, i want to make it work over the IP. Like you asked earlier, i checked and my browser isn't caching the images, it is able to load via the localhost, what i want is to make it work over IP too!

Comment: I just tested that by putting somedomain.com in my local hosts file pointing to your IP but it didn't work.  As soon as I changed imdb.com to point to your IP it worked perfectly.

Comment: Imdb doesn't like pulling images, u could use the [Imdb API](http://imdbapi.org/) here instead

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the workaround I suggested earlier.

Answer (score 1):

U could use the [Imdb API](http://imdbapi.org/)

Just request the data with : `http://imdbapi.org/?id={id}&type=json&plot=simple&episode=1&lang=en-US&aka=simple&release=simple`

{id} being the imdb id of the movie. Then u can access the picture with :

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://imdbapi.org/?id={id}&type=json&plot=simple&episode=1&lang=en-US&aka=simple&release=simple"));
$img = $data->poster;
```